# NSTimer interfering with user clicks

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nstimer

I am trying to update a SwiftUI `Image` very frequently. That image view is clickable and gets a highlight if selected.

When using an NSTimer with a short interval (0.25 seconds) for the image update, my SwiftUI view does not respond properly to user clicks anymore - clicks are only caught intermittently. If I set the timer interval to 1 second, things would work fine, however, that's not possible in my specific situation.

How can I ensure that my SwiftUI `Image`'s `onTapGesture` works smoothly even with a high timer frequency?

The timer is declared as such:

```swift
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }

            // updating an observable object here which will be propagated to the ScreenElement view below
        })
        timer.tolerance = 0.2

        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

Then I have the SwiftUI view declared as such:

```swift
struct ScreenElement: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12)
        {
            Image(nsImage: screen.imageData)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(174/105, contentMode: .fit)
                .background(Asset.gray900.swiftUIColor)
                .cornerRadius(12)

            Text(screen.name)
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
        .onTapGesture {
            // modify data source and mark this current element as the highlighted (selected) one
        }
    }
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I tried to move the timer to a background thread which didn't really work and/or caused more problems than it solved. Additionally, I tried to increase the timer interval, which, however, is not feasible in my use case since it has to be a very high refresh rate.

**Some further considerations I had but couldn't answer:**

Is it maybe possible that SwiftUI just doesn't support a frequent refresh of 4x per second? Or did I maybe use the wrong UI Element to handle the tap gesture in my particular case? Or is it just not possible to have a timer with such frequent updates since it overloads the main thread?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into TimelineView

Comment: How long does the timer code need to complete? (Don't guess, measure it.)

Comment: @Codo how do I measure it?

Comment: Use Xcode Instruments / CPU profiling and drill down to the code. Or use CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() at the start and end of the block, average across 10 or 100 executions and print it.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine on an iPhone and Mac, all taps are recognised and it's updating at 10 times per second:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let imageNames = ["eraser", "lasso.and.sparkles", "folder.badge.minus", "externaldrive.badge.xmark", "calendar.badge.plus", "arrowshape.zigzag.forward", "newspaper.circle", "shareplay", "person.crop.square.filled.and.at.rectangle.fill"]
    
    @State private var currentImageNames: [String] = ["", "", ""]
    @State private var selected: Int?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { index in
                        Image(systemName: currentImageNames[index])
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 60)
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selected = index
                            }
                            .background(
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(selected == index ? .red : .blue)
                            )
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            addTimer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func addTimer() {
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
            currentImageNames = [imageNames.randomElement()!, imageNames.randomElement()!, imageNames.randomElement()!]
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }
}
```

Is there something else you're possibly doing that is blocking the main queue?

Comment: yes there is - I am processing the image data that will be displayed in the view later. If the timer callback is empty there's no problem so I think I have to get it to the background queue or something...

Comment: Can you add the image data processing you're doing to your question?